# Laravel undefined method Passport::client()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

When trying to run `php artisan db:seed` for my app, the other seeders run successfully but this one in particular throws the following error:

```
In OAUTHTableSeeder.php line 14:
  Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Passport::client()
```

The seeder in question is this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class OAUTHTableSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run(){
        $client = Passport::client()->forceFill([
            'user_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Password Grant Client',
            'secret' => '1234',
            'redirect' => 'http://localhost',
            'personal_access_client' => false,
            'password_client' => true,
            'revoked' => false,
        ]);

        $client->save();
    }
}
```

This runs fine in a remote environment and I can't figure out what is different between the two. I've tried removing the `vendor` directory and reinstalling dependencies via composer, but to no avail.

Comment: did you install the passport on your local environment?

Comment: can you try to 'composer dump-autoload' ? Maybe it is just about the autoload not having passport in its list, if you just pulled the vendor from remote source